# Can AssertJ traverse a JSON API response to verify the path of a node?

Tags: java, json, hamcrest, assertj

Hamcrest library has a very clean way of traversing a JSON API response to verify the path of a node by using a method called `hasJsonPath`

```
assertThat(responseBody, hasJsonPath("$.record.book.author", equalTo("john")));
```

However, I am struggling to find a similar way to find a path and verifying it using AssertJ. I was expecting something like this would work, but it won't compile

```
 assertThat(responseBody).hasJsonPath("$.record.book.author", equalTo("john"));
```

Can AssertJ traverse a node and verify its existence and its value?

Answer (score 3):

Prefer using https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit over generic assertions library, it has a really nice API to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Joel Costigliola. I will give JsonUnit a  try